# Check Object Existence in TCL

Tags: tcl, itcl

I want to check that whether object exists or not in tcl.
I looked into `info object` options but didn't found something specific for object existence and `info exists` only works for variables not objects.

Any idea?
I created an object of struct::stack
`::struct::stack aa
(Dcode) 52 % info object class aa
::struct::stack::stack_oo`

It seems that it is in tcloo.
I think in Itcl find command works `itcl::find object aa`

But not aware of tcl_oo.

Answer (score 3):

You probably just missed it: `info object isa object` is used to test whether a particular word refers to an object.

```
% info object isa object abcde
0
% oo::object create abcde
::abcde
% info object isa object abcde
1
% abcde destroy
% info object isa object abcde
0
```

Here, with some other commands…

```
% info object isa object oo::object
1
% info object isa object while
0
% info object isa object no.such.thing.at.all.ever
0
```

Comment: my bad...should have checked this. Thanks